# problem with telnet HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Tags: networking, telnet

I was trying to do this:

Telnet into a Web server and send a multiline request message. Include in the request message the If-modified-since: header line to force a response message with the 304 Not Modified status code.

so I did steps below

```
telnet example.com 80
```

and then

```
GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
```

and two enter.
and I got some information.
I added

```
If-modified-since: Thu, 17 Oct 2019 06:18:26 GMT
```

but still no 304 not modified.

[this is what I get after GEt and Host](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wNRY.png)

and

```
HTTP/1.0 501 Not Implemented
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 357
Connection: close
Date: Fri, 30 Apr 2021 16:10:33 GMT
Server: ECSF (dcb/7F80)
```

Comment: What status code are you getting now?

Comment: @Exampleperson I'm really confused, after GET and Host it gives me some information and some code and when I enter if modified again some code and "connection lost".

Comment: something could be wrong with the server.

Comment: Show me full request.

Comment: @Exampleperson it's hidden in cmd that's exactly what I wrote above. am I doing anything wrong??

Comment: so you are using windows telnet?

Comment: What status code do you get?

Comment: @Exampleperson yes

Comment: @Exampleperson I added a picture

Comment: Maybe 304 is disabled server side.

Comment: @Exampleperson so how should I find a website with this error?:)

Comment: what? I cannot understand what you mean. Why should you find a website with this error? And what error? This whole 200 instead of 304 is not an error.

Comment: @Exampleperson cause I have to use telnet and get 304 Not Modified status code from some website.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP/1.1 needs the Host header.
Your request should be:

```
GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
Host: hostname.tld
```

### Edit

So if you are connecting to example.com:

```
GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
```

Comment: host name should be the address of the site? still I don't get 304 not modified:(

Comment: @negar, it should be the domain name of the site. Including the subdomains. Example: So, it would be www.google.com if you are connected to www.google.com, and google.com if you are connected to google.com.

Comment: @negar show your full HTTP request. You can ofcourse hide any private info while showing it

Comment: could you give me an example, please?

Comment: @negar see my answer now

Comment: @negar, what is your If-Modified-Since header content?